# regex to match words of length specified within string

Tags: python, regex, samtools

I am trying to parse the text output from samtools mpileup. I start with a string

```
s = '.$......+2AG.+2AG.+2AGGG'
```

Whenever I have a `+` followed by an integer `n`, I would like to select n characters following that integer and replace the whole thing by `*`. So for this test case I would have

```
'.$......+2AG.+2AG.+2AGGG' ---> '.$......*.*.*GG'
```

I have the regex  `\+[0-9]+[ACGTNacgtn]+` but that results in the output `.$......*.*.*` and the trailing G's are lost as well. How do I select n characters where the n is not known ahead of time but specified in the string itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `repl` argument in `re.sub` can be a string or a **function**.

So, you can do very complex things with function replacements:

```py
def removechars(m):
    x=m.group()
    n=re.match(r'\+(\d+).*', x).group(1) # digit part
    return '*'+x[1+len(n)+int(n):]
```

Solves your problem:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\+[0-9]+[ACGTNacgtn]+', removechars, s)
'.$......*.*.*GG'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant, but I pulled out the numeric values using `re.findall` before running `re.sub`.

```
ls=re.findall('\+(\d)',s)

for i in ls:
    s=re.sub('\+(%s\w{%s})' % (i,i),'*',s)
```